# Agrupando select por quantidade de linhas

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

Tenho o select abaixo, onde o resultado total de linhas sem agrupamento é de 208k, porém, agrupando e trazendo o resultado com JSON, tenho clientes com muitas linhas impossibilitando o processamento da aplicação.

**Ex:** Cliente X com 5k de produtos

Gostaria de ajuda para que o agrupamento fosse por no máximo 100 produtos, ou seja, se um cliente tiver 5k de produtos que atende as criterios do select, trazer somente 100 produtos por linha no Json e por cliente.

**Exemplo:**
{"helena_cliente_code" : "cliente_X", "id_promocao" : "16812", "produtos" : [{"produto_id" : "fdfadf16516314631s6116", "id_promocao_produto_sku_status" : "REJECTED"},{outros 99 aqui...}]}
{"helena_cliente_code" : "cliente_X", "id_promocao" : "16812", "produtos" : [{"produto_id" : "5df1a3aoife54584dfadfa", "id_promocao_produto_sku_status" : "REJECTED"},{outros 99 aqui...}]}
.....

**Obs:** Com o select abaixo o resultado é todos os produtos independente da quantidade retornado ai gostaria de limitar isso.

```
select 
    json_build_object(
        'helena_cliente_code', sa.helena_cliente_code,
        'id_promocao', p.id_promocao,
        'produtos', json_agg(json_build_object('produto_id', pps.id_produto_sku, 'id_promocao_produto_sku_status', 'REJECTED'))
    ) json_final,
    sa.id_cliente 
from i.promocao p
    inner join i.promocao_produto_sku pps on p.id = pps.id_promocao
    inner join i.cliente_atributos sa on sa.id_cliente = p.id_cliente
    inner join i.produto_sku ps on ps.id = pps.id_produto_sku 
where ps.ativo_venda =true 
and ps.id_produto_sku_status ='ONLINE' 
and pps.id_promocao_produto_sku_status = 'APROVADO' 
and p.atualizacao  >= now() - interval '10 day'
group by sa.id_cliente, p.id_promocao;
```

Comment: já tentou usar `limit`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html

Comment: Já tinha tentado não funciona, o limit ai vai limitar a quantidade de linhas retornadas, ou seja, vai trazer 100 (limit 100) linhas com clientes com todos os produtos, independente da quantidade de produtos 100 ou mais.

Comment: Qual a linguagem desta aplicação no back-end?

Comment: O back end é em Python3 !